# iPhone simulator plays video, real device won't

Tags: ios, swift, video, avkit

I am building an app in Swift on Xcode 7.2

I added a video to my ViewController. Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class GymViewController: UIViewController {





var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerView = AVPlayer()

let fileFemaleURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/marienkoen/Documents/AppDevelopment/ROZsport/ROZsport/GymFemale-2434.m4v")


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
}



@IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


playerView = AVPlayer(URL: fileFemaleURL)

playerViewController.player = playerView

self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true){
self.playerViewController.player?.play()
}
```

I can play this video when running the app in the simulator, but it will not work on a real device. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the hints. I created these:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"m4v")
```

And called them in the button action:

```
@IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

playerView = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
playerViewController.player = playerView

self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true){
self.playerViewController.player?.play()}}
```

And it WORKS!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because your path you was using is from simulator, on real device it changed.
if you added this file to your project, you can get this url via:

```
func getDocumentsURL() -> NSURL {
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    return documentsURL
}

func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String {

    let fileURL = getDocumentsURL().URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    return fileURL.path!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the file name is hardcoded in the code and the file path is from local system path on your Mac device. When you run the code on the Simulator it is running on your Mac so it is able to locate the file path. However, when you run it on the device, it is unable to get access to the provided path location. Hence, the issue. If it is the path of the video available on your mobile device or a public URL that will be accessible when you are running the app on the mobile device.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is that filenames are case-sensitive on the iPhone, but not in the simulator?

Comment: its the path...it seem like he using the file on his computer lol

Comment: Yep, he is. He's a newbie!

Answer (score -1):

For some future dev who runs into this thread .... I ran into this question today while troubleshooting the same issue on xcode 15.1 swift 5.x.  My videos played in simulator but not on test device, ipad mini 2 running ios 12.5.7.

I spent a lot of time testing and talking to chatgpt about possible issues. Checked codec of quicktime player screen recording (H.264) among other settings.  Ultimately, I figured out this line of code was causing the play and the player controls to disappear, but audio still played.

```
playerController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Removing this line made videos play as desired with the controls visible. It doesn't seem to effect the simulator at all but the older ipad mini didn't like it.

Comment: But this isn't related to the question at all. The issue in the question is due to a path issue. When answering a question you should address the whole question, not just the vague title.

Comment: The vague question got me here.  Since the real answer here is different )from what I needed to do), and the rest of the code was good resolve the vague question for them, reading the answer to this question, I new the rest of their code worked; and this helped me fix the issue in my code .