# Button triggering video to open and play

Tags: ios, swift, button, video

I am very new to coding and have no experience.
I have found a way to make a video play but it autoplays / autopens. I need the video to only open and play when a button is pressed. Please can someone help me tweak my code to do this.

This is my current code:

```
import UIKit
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var playerviewcontroller = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerview = AVPlayer ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        var fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/MorganEvans/Documents/Apps/Warm Up/Video View/Video View/ViewController.swift")
        playerview = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

        playerviewcontroller.player = playerview

        self.presentViewController(playerviewcontroller, animated: true){

            self.playerviewcontroller.player?.play()
        }


    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func playMusic(sender: AnyObject) {
    var fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/Users/MorganEvans/Documents/Apps/Warm Up/Video View/Video View/ViewController.swift")
    playerview = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

    playerviewcontroller.player = playerview

    self.presentViewController(playerviewcontroller, animated: true){

        self.playerviewcontroller.player?.play()
    }
}
```

You can simply put it anywhere in your `ViewController`, as long as it is not inside another function.

Then connect it with a button in your storyboard:

[image: How to connect]

Comment: This is Perfect! Thanks so much! I really appreciate the screenshot. When I preview the app on my iphone, the video doesn't play. Please help

Comment: Does it play with your original code? Also, try putting a print("function ran") inside the IBAction

Comment: It does not play on iphone with the original code either only in simulator.

Comment: Check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265411/iphone-simulator-plays-video-real-device-wont

Comment: so I add func getDocumentsURL() -> NSURL {
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    return documentsURL
}

func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String {

    let fileURL = getDocumentsURL().URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    return fileURL.path!

}

Comment: Sure. Try out the different solutions and let me know how it goes!

Comment: I have tried this but I don't know how to use that code. Like where to put the path in. Please help

Answer (score 1):

this is how a button would set up to look, this example is pulling a movie from firebase but other than that this is how it would look

```
@IBAction func playV(sender: UIButton) {
   
        

     
          
            let amovieUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/messenger-test-d225b.appspot.com/o/test%2FTestVideo.mov?alt=media&token=bd4ccba3-b446-43bc-809e-b1152aa3c2ff")
            if let aurl = amovieUrl {
                self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: aurl as URL)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
        
self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()

   
}

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an **Action Connection** [as explained here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingAction.html).
2. Move that code in `viewDidAppear` to the action you created in step 1.
3. Profit.

Also, you don't need those default implementation for `viewDidLoad` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning`:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var playerviewcontroller = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerview = AVPlayer ()

@IBAction func yourActionForButton(sender: UIButton) {
    // Your code.
}
```

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for your help. So I have got this far:
    @IBAction func Button(sender: AnyObject) But where do I put the code? Sorry to be a pain thanks